# Group by and display count in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, group-by, count, categorization

I am trying to learn some Excel's features and I want to know if it is possible to make an SQL-like statement in Excel.

For example, I distincted a dataset and the output is:

```
date     name    class
20210101  ted     a
20210101  nick    b
20210110  george  c
```

I want to make a `count(*)` and a `group by` like:

```
select count(*), name, class
from table
group by name, class
```

Comment: Check Pivot Tables.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks for your quick response. I found pivot but it makes a sum in dates. I want to count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial data:
[image]

Create a pivot table.

When you drag columns like this...
[image]

...your pivot table will look like this:
[image]

Right click on "Sum of date" -> "Value Field Settings..."
Choose "Count" -> "OK"

[image]

If you like, you can separate those fields which are stacked in "Rows".
Right click the value of outer level category in "Rows" (e.g. "ted") -> "Field Settings..."

1. Tab "Subtotals & Filters", under "Subtotals" select "None"
2. Tab "Layout & Print", under "Layout" select "Show item labels in tabular form"
3. OK

[image]