# Excel technique to indicate which name has more than one program_name

Tags: excel

I have a list of clients in a facility. They can be in one of 2 programs, or in both. The data looks like this: so that we are interested here in Steve because he is in 2 programs
I would be intereted in either a sepate excell with only cases like Steve or a column can be added that would indicate that these name is in more than one program_name.

```
name                program_name
Bocoster, Steve        Foster
Bocoster, Steve        Therapy
Ladinot, Brelle        Therapy
Gayle, Gol             Therapy
Jones, Jim             Foster
```

Comment: Can't you just do `countif` on the names?

Comment: Countif would count the cells. I want to count where the name has a record in both program_name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by and display count in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817129/group-by-and-display-count-in-excel)

Comment: So a name could be listed twice with the same program?

Comment: yes for a mental health facility with many programs so a person can be in more than 1 program that is what they want to know who is in more than 1.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You want a Pivot Table, which gives you 
[image]

You can then sort by Grand Total to get those with 2 together.
See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576